# Add Alt + F7 as shortcut to an action in Netbeans platform

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, netbeans-platform

I am developing a programming tool on the Netbeans Platform.
In that, I have an action to find usages and I want to add <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> as a shortcut to fire my action. I have implemented this for <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> and some other shortcuts.

But in this case, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> is already used in the Netbeans Platform to find usages.

How can I override <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> ?

Here is what I have already done:

```
@ActionRegistration(displayName = "#CTL_FindUsagesAction")
@ActionReferences(value = {
    @ActionReference(path = "Shortcuts", name = "A-F7"),
```

Comment: What about if you change Alt + F7  to another key code that is an unused character and then use the changeable key. or by coding prevent   Alt + F7 and map it to another character and then use the other characters.

Comment: @i_th I have tried that but that is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the following link where you can remove or add keymap for the project itself. Another suggestion, you can prevent Alt + F7 character when keypress and map it to another character and then use the other characters.

[image]

Source:https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/keymap_option_panel/

Read also this:https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=249671

Answer (score 3):

You could try to disable or change the shortcut using alt + f7 via a custom keymap.

Tools>Options>Keymap

http://wiki.netbeans.org/Keyboard_Shortcuts

Comment: yeah, that is true. But that is from the customers' side. What I want to do is  make it a default shortcut